# properties repeat in object array

Tags: javascript

So I am working on the following array of objects having two properties name and type

```
  var pole = [
   {
       name: "Mike",
       type: "Pency",
   },
   {
       name: "Lesssy",
       type: "Pike",

   },
   {
       name: "Orcha",
       type: "Roo",
   },
   {
       name: "Roosvelt",
       type: "Zean",

   },
   {
       name: "Orange",
       type: "Pike",
   },
   {
       name: "Searie",
       type: "Zean",

   } ....... 100 Times
```

What Javascript method can be used to get count of top 3 most common 'names' and number of occurence

Comment: How would you do it manually with pencil and paper?

Comment: @PM77-1 : Edited my question. I want to know how to implement it in JS

Comment: step 1: do you want 10 or 3 most common? step 2: ??? step 3: profit

Comment: @sarah - by writing code, not having it all written for you

Comment: Is this a school/university question?

Comment: Unless you clearly understand how to accomplish this task manually, you will not be able to program it.

Comment: @PM77-1 : I got the idea that I will use a data structure called map with name as key and value: number of occurences. I am asking so that I know I am thinking in right direction

Comment: @sarah `.reduce` is a good start - you'll want `.sort`, and `.slice` as well as `.map`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Yes,  using Map is a  sensible approach .

Comment: @sarah you keep ignoring everybody's advice, but it's all good. You don't need to find some special js code to do this, before you understand the logic you're actually trying to implement. Right now your question isn't much better than asking "what words to I need to use to write a story?". You could do this with `reduce`, or a `for` loop; by tallying in an `Object` or a `Map`; you could sort by `name` then count how many of the same name are in sequence; you could build a damn generator `function*` and assign back in the `yield` using `next()`. It's a programming challenge, not a JS one.

Comment: Thank you all. Working on the challenge. Will post my solution

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a University/School question, and for that reason I don't want to give you the full answer but consider these steps for a simple (and inefficient) algorithm:

```
1) Keep track of all the names that you have found in the list

2) Include a counter for each of the names in terms of how often they pop up.

3) Loop through the array

4) counter++ each time its respective name pops up

5) Sort the list depending on the counter's count

6) return the top 3 (or 10, your question was unclear how many you wanted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
function topN(obj, prop, n) {
  var groups = obj.reduce(function (res, i) {
    res[i[prop]] = (res[i[prop]] || 0) + 1;
    return res;
  }, {});

  var sortable = Object.keys(groups).reduce(function (res, i) {
    res.push({name: i, value: groups[i]});
    return res;
  }, []);

  sortable.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
  });

  var result = sortable.filter(function (item, index) {
    return index < n;
  }).map(function (i) {
    return i.name;
  });

  console.log(result);
}

topN(pole, 'name', 10);
topN(pole, 'type', 10);
```

Comment: booooooooooooooo